# How to Handle the iBeacons overlapping eachother

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ibeacon

I have created a app for detecting the beacons. things are going on good. the problem that I have is:
When there are more beacons overlapping on one another. how am I suppose to handle the situation considering the case 
1. When we want to receive the offer only once from a particular beacon on entering to the beacon/we are in the place where we have more than one beacon overlapping each other.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe by checking the proximity?

Answer (score 1):

When you have overlapping iBeacons, it is important to design the iBeacon identifiers (UUID, major, minor) and the `CLBeaconRegions` you use to monitor them so that you get the results you want.

Do you want to trigger "the offer" whenever any of the overlapping iBeacons are detected?  If so, then monitor for a `CLBeaconRegion` that matches them all, probably by setting just the UUID (and maybe the major if all beacons share that value.)  In this case, you will only get *one* Region entry notification when any of them are detected.  You won't get one for each overlapping iBeacon.

If you only want to trigger "the offer" when a single one of the overlapping iBeacons is detected, then monitor for a `CLBeaconRegion` that only matches that one iBeacon, typically by specifying the UUID, major, and minor in that `CLBeaconRegion`.  Of course, you also need to ensure that each iBeacon is configured with a different minor.  Remember, too, that you can monitor for multiple `CLBeaconRegions` simultaneously, if needed, and get a specific callback for each one.

While it a separate issue from overlapping iBeacons, if you really want users to "receive the offer only once", you also need to add a filter to your detection callback.  A glitch in iOS sometimes gives you a very quick exited region callback followed by an almost instantaneous entered region callback.  In order to prevent users from getting the offer a second time, store off the timestamp of the last time the offer was pushed to the user, and only push it again if enough time has passed (say 1 hour or one day.) [See this answer for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199288/ibeacon-enter-and-exit-region-constantly-every-1-minute)

Answer (score 0):

My workflow at the moment is to detect in the didRangeBeacons method the Beacon which is the closest to my actual position. This is done by comparing for each beacon the rssi property.

After identifying the closest Beacon I process the desired action for this beacon.

To avoid that this action is triggered repeatedly (beacause the didRangeBeacons method is triggered a couple of times per seconds) I implemented an isLocked Flag (BOOL) in my actual beaconHandler, which does the processing.

So I only react to the Beacon which is the closest to me. And I only react once. I also keep track of my last beacon which I identified as closest. This enables me to react immediatly, If you are getting in Range of another beacon. So e.g. when you walk along a store, every beacon is triggered immediatly, but not repeatedly.

Comment: and off course they are all configured unique on hardware level, i.e. one puuid for all my beacons, and each beacon with a different major/minor id configuration